# In their new layout, How does youtube keep the flash video playing when you go to a users profile page from the video page?

Tags: java, html, flash, youtube

In the cosmicpanda update for youtube, you can go from a video page to the video creators profile page while your video is still playing in flash.

Does anyone how Youtube accomplishes this? I would like to know if it's possible to keep the flash state of a site constant while moving from page to page on a site.

It doesn't seem as if the flash is reloading, so I don't think that they are just saving cookies for the current video time and starting the video at that point when they refresh.

I would assume that they're using ajax, but the application of this feature is really clean. The URL gets correctly changed to the users' profile page's URL. The back button still works as it should. (I can press back and forward between video page and user profile page and the video continues going clean and never drops.)

Comment: This is really quite incredible, what do you mean by "cosmic panda update"?

Comment: It's the name of their new layout; http://www.youtube.com/cosmicpanda

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be an application of HTML5 history.  [Mozilla has another more accessible example.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/demos/detail/html5-history-gallery-demo)  Major libraries are starting to support this functionality and [YUI is building a client side MVC framework using it](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/app/).

Comment: Of course!  Pretty much every sophisticated web site these days uses some sort of ajax interactions.

Comment: Yea, I didn't know that devs loaded entire pages with ajax. I thought it was generally used for smaller items on a page. But cool! Also, I guess the change in the URL can be done with javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 0):

It is like making the browsers back and forward buttons work with ajax!
You can find more details on the given link http://ajaxhistory.com/
And example link is http://ajaxhistory.com/example/